# how to change pie chart colors using dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I am new user of `DC.JS`. I am using `dc.piechart`. I'm having issues change `pie slice` colors using a `dc.pieChart`.

Documentation and examples I've seen use the colors method and many combination seen from Google. I want to bind a particular color for a particular data.

which I used the code for change color but still not working mentioned bellow.

```
   .colors(["#eeff00","#ff0022"]);
```

another approach-

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["banana", "cherry", "blueberry"])                           
.range(["#eeff00", "#ff0022", "#2200ff"]); 
pie.colors(function(d){ return colorScale(d.fruitType); });
```

Any idea about how to solve the problem?

Comment: Your second approach is closer, but I think you should just pass the colorScale there and not wrap it in a function. Also do the fruitType part in the [colorAccessor](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#coloraccessorcoloraccessorfunction)

Answer (score 5):

you need to generate a ordinal scale first.

```
.colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(
  [ '#1f78b4', '#b2df8a', '#cab2d6'..., '#bc80bd']);
```

The first slice would take the first color, second the second and so on.

A gordon pointed out, there is a convenience method too:

```
// convenience method, the same as above
chart.ordinalColors(['#1f78b4', '#b2df8a', '#cab2d6'...]);
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#colorscolorscale

Comment: colors are repeating, what can be done to avoid that ?